# How can I run exec() command locally from server php script

Tags: php, command, system

I have a php script in Linux server with

exec('whoami'); command.

But I want to run this command in the machine that will run my script from server.

Means that script will run in server but this command I want to run in client machine. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Without a helper application it's impossible to run exec() client-side from server-side.

Comment: There's no such thing as a stupid question providing it conforms to this websites guidelines.